# EditText is being rendered incorrectly

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have a layout which is being rendered as below image:
[Layout being rendered on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mXtb.png)

It should be something like this, as being shown in Android Studio.
[Layout being shown in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0waQi.png)

This is not device dependent issue and coming to all the device.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by downgrading the gradle version to 2.1.2.

Comment: There is also an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213942&can=4&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) about it.